# $B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+}$ with the norm $\Vert\vert \cdot \Vert\vert _{\sqrt{2}}$ don't have normal structure

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-points

Consider the space $\ell ^{2}$ with the standard norm 
\begin{align*}
\Vert x \Vert _{2} = \left( \sum _{i =1} ^{\infty} x _{i} ^{2} \right) ^{1/2}
\end{align*}
and we define the equivalent norm
\begin{align*}
\Vert\vert x \Vert\vert _{\sqrt{2}}= \max\{ \Vert x \Vert _{2}, \sqrt{2}\Vert x \Vert _{\infty} \} \mbox{.}
\end{align*}

Let's define the positive part of the unit ball
\begin{align*}
B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+} = \lbrace x \in \ell ^{2}: \; \Vert x \Vert _{2} \leqslant 1, \; x _{i} \geqslant 0 \rbrace \mbox{.}
\end{align*}
I want show that $B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+}$ with the norm $\Vert\vert \cdot \Vert\vert _{\sqrt{2}}$ don't have normal structure, and for show that, I should show that diam$(B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+})$ = $r _{x}(B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+})$. I showed that diam$(B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+}) = 1$,  but I don't know why $r _{x}(B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+}) =1$. What element in $B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+}$ can take for prove that $r _{x}(B _{\ell ^{2}} ^{+}) =1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $x_i=2^{-i/2}$, and then the distance of this element from zero is precisely $1$ in your norm, because the sum of the squares is $1$ and the supremum is $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for help me :)

Comment: the sequence $ y$ with each $ y_ {i} = 2 ^ {- 1/2} $ if it belongs to the ball, but the norm of $ x - and $ has a different result:  how $\Vert\vert x - y \Vert\vert _{\sqrt{2}}= \max \{ \Vert x - y \Vert _{2}, \sqrt{2} \Vert x - y \Vert _{\infty} \}$, so we have that

Comment: \begin{align*}
\Vert x - y \Vert _{2} &= \left( \sum _{i = 1} ^{\infty}  (x - y) \right) ^{1/2} \\
&= \left( \sum _{i = 1} ^{\infty}  x _{i} ^{2} - 2 \sum _{i = 1} ^{\infty}  \frac{x _{i}}{2 ^{i/2}} + \sum _{i = 1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 ^{i/2}} \right) ^{1/2}
\end{align*}